# How to get a non null userInfo after the first time to my @selector(method)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have a code like the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemPlayEnded:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil userInfo:userInfo];
```

In the selector method:

```
- (void)itemPlayEnded:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Entered itemPlayEnded");

    AVPlayerItem *p = [notification object];
    NSLog(@"userinfo description %@",[[notification userInfo] description]);
}
```

The first time the `itemPlayEnded` is accessed the `userInfo` is non-`null`. After the first time the value is `null`.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? Why `null` value for `userInfo` after the first time?

EDIT:

I need to clarify what is happening. I also updated my Notification code to use the lastItem which is a AVPlayerItem.

```
queuePlayer = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] init];
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{@"tones": copyoftones};

for (NSString *playThis in listOfTonesToBePlayed) {
    NSString *soundPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:playThis ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *soundURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    AVPlayerItem *thePlayerItemA = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:soundURL];
    lastItem = thePlayerItemA;
    [queuePlayer insertItem:thePlayerItemA afterItem:nil];
}
queuePlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance;


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemPlayEnded:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:lastItem];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:lastItem userInfo:userInfo];

[queuePlayer play];
```

What happens.

1. before the queuePlayer is able to play a tone the itemPlayEnded is entered along with the Dictionary non nil
2. Next the list of tones are played
3. The itemPlayEnded is re-entered with the Dictionary nil.

I wanted to use code to reset the Notification inside of the itemPlayEnded method with something like the following (p is a AVPlayerItem which is the lastItem from the code with the Notification):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:p];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemPlayEnded:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:p];        
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:p userInfo:userInfo];

[queuePlayer play];
```

But then the itemPlayEnded method is re-entered in a never-ending loop without playing the player.  A race condition.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 2:
I have determined that the offending code is:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:lastItem userInfo:userInfo];
```

some how I need to set the object to use the correct sender. Not sure yet on what to put there.

EDIT 3:

What I really wanted to do was be able to loop thru the complete sequence of sounds or mp3s. I finally figured that what I was trying to do here was not going to work like I wanted it.  So, I ended up using the class from https://github.com/dgiovann/AVQueuePlayerPrevious and this worked out great for me!

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the poster of the notification is passing a non nil dictionary?

Comment: Yes, the first time it is non nil , after the first time it is nil. Perhaps somebody could explain to me  why?

Comment: So, how is it getting invoked these other times?

Comment: As CrimsonChris mentions below it is with AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification . At the end of playing a sound file.  I am going to take CrimsonChris advice and read more about how AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification is called. I was expecting it to use the same userInfo for each call but it appears that it is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subscribing to the AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification which is being posted first by yourself (with some user info) and then posted again, this time NOT by you and therefore may or may not contain any user info. Refer to the documentation to see when and why Apple will post this notification and what information you can expect with it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I am counting this the answer even though I ended up using a different method to get my results.